# Using cin to read multiple int on one line

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I am trying to take integers as input from a file using cin. The file is set up in a way that there are two separated integers in each line, which I need to read separately. For example:

> 1    3
>
> 2    5
>
> 2    23

I want this in a while loop that runs to the end of the file. How can I do this?

Note: This is my first time using c++ so I am very unfamiliar with it

Comment: You can run a while loop which would keep reading from the file and keep concatenating the string into the main string. Beyond that, work on your own. :)

Comment: Since you say that you are new to C++, I would like to warn you about using input functions like `std::cin` to process your input. Using functions like `std::cin` to automatically convert your input to integers is convenient, but is not at all robust against mis-input. It's generally much better form to take input into a string and then parse the data yourself, as you then have much better control over error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy, just use a `while` loop with `cin`, and deal with each number inside the loop.

```
int x;
while(cin >> x){
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: if I want to read in two at a time would I do cin >> x >> y ?

Comment: Yes, but off the top of my head I'm not sure what would happen if you had an uneven amount of numbers in the file. Most likely, however, you would never see that final number though.

Comment: Yes, the last, lonely number would be skipped. And there would be no way to distinguish this case from normal end of file.